# Uploading Documents into Sharepoint Server from .Net WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a developed a webapplication which has a functionality to upload/download the documents into Sharepoint. It is working correctly in my local machine.

After Deployment in server(IIS), i am not able to upload the documents.

Is there any settings needs to be done in IIS, or please let me know what i am missing here..
Appreciate your help...

Below is the code i am using to upload file...I am not able to capture error message now as sharepoint server is down now...

```
    NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariablesBO.UserID, GlobalVariablesBO.Password, GlobalVariablesBO.Domain);
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.Credentials = myCred;
        //webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "anything");
        webclient.UploadFile(dBO.URL, "PUT", dBO.SPFileName);            
        webclient.Dispose();
```

Comment: "not able to upload the documents" ... Any error ? Double check permission settings.

Comment: error message? are you using the client object model?

Comment: You will need to provide some more information and some code for people to be able the help you. Error messages as in exceptions do also help the process.

Comment: Updated code information...